# How can i write DAO layer for my update\get all entities

Tags: java, servlets, dao

guys, i stuck into the middle on process writing my own first web-app. I have a couple issues with DAO layer.
Look at my first entity:

```
public class Fabric {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
}
```

There is Object, which "id" property is the foreign key for another entity:

```
public class Guitar {

    private Integer id;
    private Fabric fabric;
    private String name;
    private Short strings;
    private Color color;
    private Integer count;
}
```

So when i try to write DAO layer for "Guitar" entity like this:

````
        Guitar guitar = null;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_BY_ID)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                guitar = Guitar.builder()
                        .id(resultSet.getInt(id))
                        ***.fabric()*** <---- idk how to get fabric id
                        .name(resultSet.getString("name"))
                        .strings(resultSet.getShort("strings"))
                        .color(???some jave code???) <--- this is ENUM :(
                        .count(resultSet.getInt("count"))
                        .build();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DaoException(e);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(guitar);
    } ``

SQL request: ```private static final String GET_BY_ID = "SELECT id, fabric_id, name, strings, color, count FROM shop_storage.guitar WHERE count NOTNULL";
````

p.s. also idk how to get enum in this object:(
If can help me - i'll appreciate it.
have a good time anyone:)

Comment: Hello maybe you should use [Spring Data Jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) who will do the DAO for you

Comment: not in this time, i wanna learn java core first

Comment: How your enum is stocked (With ordinal value or enum code )

Comment: My enum seem like this:
```@Getter
public enum Color {
    RED("Red"),
    YELLOW("Yellow"),
    BLACK("Black"),
    ORANGE("Orange"),
    WHITE("White"),
    BROWN("Brown"),
    BLUE("Blue");

    private String name;

    Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Color getByName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(it -> it.getName().equals(name))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}```

Comment: Yes but in your database you have a colum with the which value ? (A code/ a int/ this is not working for the moment )

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE guitar
(
    id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    fabric_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
     FOREIGN KEY (fabric_id) REFERENCES fabric (id),
    name      CHARACTER VARYING(128),
    strings   SMALLINT,
    color     CHARACTER VARYING(128),
    count     INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Ok i suppose, toString is utilise to stock the enum. 
So you can do something like that.
```
      .color(Color.valueOf(resulSet.getString("color"))) 
```

Comment: And for the fabric add a fabricDao layer who will to the same job (not optimal but for a first try that should be enough)